# Select struct definition from multiple ones based on platform

Tags: c++, api, cross-platform

Is it possible to have one struct, but two definitions, where the definition is selected via a #define macro? For example:

platform.h

```
struct Context;
```

platform_win32.cc:

```
#include "platform.h"

struct Context
{
  // win32 specific implementation..
  bool win;
}
```

platform_linux.cc:

```
#include "platform.h"

struct Context
{
  //Linux specific implementation..
  bool lin;
}
```

platform.cc:

```
#define WIN32 //For testing reasons

#ifdef WIN32
  #include "platform_win32.cc"
#endif

#ifdef LINUX
  #include "platform_linux.cc"
#endif
```

main.cc:

```
#include "platform.h"

int main()
{
  Context *context = new Context;
  context->win=true;

  return 0;
}
```

But, this does not compile and returns:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Context'
note: forward declaration of 'struct Context'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the declare of type should be write into '.h' file, other than '.cc' or '.c' file.

Secondly, you can declare different type of struct for different platform by #define, like you did.

For example:

platform_win32.h:

```
struct Context
{
  // win32 specific implementation..
  bool field1;
  bool field2;
  bool field_win_specified;
}
```

platform_linux.h:

```
struct Context
{
  //Linux specific implementation..
  bool field1;
  bool field2;
  bool field_linux_specified;
}
```

platform.h:

```
#ifdef WIN32
  #include "platform_win32.h"
#endif

#ifdef LINUX
  #include "platform_linux.h"
#endif
```

main.cc:

```
#include "platform.h"

int main()
{
  Context *context = new Context;
  context->field1=true;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bye the way, because we can not avoid to include a '.h' file more than one time, you should to define tokens to clear up these compiling error(s):
e.g., in platform_linux.h file:
```
#ifndef PLATFORM_LINUX_H_
#define PLATFORM_LINUX_H_


//......


#endif // PLATFORM_LINUX_H__
```

Answer (score 0):

For forward-declare like `struct Context;`

The main rule is that you can only use where memory layout (and thus member functions and data members) do not need to be known in the file you forward-declare it.

Possible fix:

platform.h

```
#define WIN32 //For testing reasons

#ifdef WIN32
  #include "platform_win32.h"
#endif

#ifdef LINUX
  #include "platform_linux.h"
#endif
```

platform_win32.h

```
struct Context
{
  // win32 specific implementation..
  bool win;
}
```

platform_linux.h

```
struct Context
{
  //Linux specific implementation..
  bool lin;
}
```

main.cc

```
#include "platform.h"

int main()
{
  Context *context = new Context;
  context->win=true;

  return 0;
}
```